# html bootstrap cant align to center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

Hey guys I am new to Stackoverflow, I have been coding in HTML for just over 5 months now. I am currently working with Boostrap. I am currently trying to modify [this](http://www.themes.alessioatzeni.com/html/brushed/index.html) website to how I like it. But I cant seem to align things properly, as shown in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dgf3L.png). As you can see there is more space on the left side and less space on the right side.

I have looked at other Stackoverflow posts with similar problems and I have looked in the CSS file and tried to find anything related to margin and modify it but I haven't been able to make it work so my section is centered properly. I am using row and span12.

Basically I am trying to align the section (`<section id="projects">`) to the center of the page

I was hoping somebody could help me. P.S where is a download link to the website

http://www.alessioatzeni.com/blog/brushed-template/

Thank you so much :)

**Update 1**
Here is my work div. I have not modified css

```
<!-- Our Work Section -->
<div id="work" class="page">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
                <div class="title-page-less-margin">
                    <h2 class="title">Our Work</h2>
                    <h3 class="title-description">Check Out Our Projects on <a href="#">Dribbble</a>.</h3>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Portfolio Projects -->

        <div class="span12">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="title-page-less-margin">
                    <nav id="options" class="work-nav">

                        <ul id="filters" class="option-set" data-option-key="filter">
                            <a href="#filter" data-option-value="*" class="selected">All Projects</a>
                            <a href="#filter" data-option-value=".design">Design</a>
                            <a href="#filter" data-option-value=".photography">Photography</a><
                            <a href="#filter" data-option-value=".video">Video</a>
                        </ul>

                    </nav>
                </div>


                <section id="projects">
                    <ul id="thumbs">

                        <!-- Item Project and Filter Name -->
                        <li class="item-thumbs span3 design">
                            <!-- Fancybox - Gallery Enabled - Title - Full Image -->
                            <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="The City" href="_include/img/work/full/image-01-full.jpg">

                                <span class="overlay-img"></span>
                                <span class="overlay-img-thumb font-icon-plus"></span>
                            </a>

                            <!-- Thumb Image and Description -->
                            <img src="_include/img/work/thumbs/image-01.jpg" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis elementum odio. Curabitur pellentesque, dolor vel pharetra mollis. hihihi">
                        </li>
                        <!-- End Item Project -->

                        <!-- Item Project and Filter Name -->
                        <li class="item-thumbs span3 design">
                            <!-- Fancybox - Gallery Enabled - Title - Full Image -->
                            <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="The Office" href="_include/img/work/full/image-02-full.jpg"></a>
                            <!-- Thumb Image and Description -->
                            <img src="_include/img/work/thumbs/image-02.jpg" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis elementum odio. Curabitur pellentesque, dolor vel pharetra mollis.">
                        </li>
                        <!-- End Item Project -->

                        <!-- Item Project and Filter Name -->
                        <li class="item-thumbs span3 photography">
                            <!-- Fancybox - Gallery Enabled - Title - Full Image -->
                            <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="The Mountains" href="_include/img/work/full/image-03-full.jpg"></a>
                            <!-- Thumb Image and Description -->
                            <img src="_include/img/work/thumbs/image-03.jpg" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis elementum odio. Curabitur pellentesque, dolor vel pharetra mollis.">
                        </li>
                        <!-- End Item Project -->

                        <!-- Item Project and Filter Name -->
                        <li class="item-thumbs span3 video">
                            <!-- Fancybox Media - Gallery Enabled - Title - Link to Video -->
                            <a class="hover-wrap fancybox-media" data-fancybox-group="video" title="Video Content From Vimeo" href="http://vimeo.com/51460511"></a>
                            <!-- Thumb Image and Description -->
                            <img src="_include/img/work/thumbs/image-08.jpg" alt="Video">
                        </li>
                        <!-- End Item Project -->

                        <!-- Item Project and Filter Name -->
                        <li class="item-thumbs span3 photography">
                            <!-- Fancybox - Gallery Enabled - Title - Full Image -->
                            <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="The Sea" href="_include/img/work/full/image-04-full.jpg"></a>
                            <!-- Thumb Image and Description -->
                            <img src="_include/img/work/thumbs/image-04.jpg" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis elementum odio. Curabitur pellentesque, dolor vel pharetra mollis.">
                        </li>
                        <!-- End Item Project -->

                        <!-- Item Project and Filter Name -->
                        <li class="item-thumbs span3 photography">
                            <!-- Fancybox - Gallery Enabled - Title - Full Image -->
                            <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Clouds" href="_include/img/work/full/image-05-full.jpg"></a>
                            <!-- Thumb Image and Description -->
                            <img src="_include/img/work/thumbs/image-05.jpg" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis elementum odio. Curabitur pellentesque, dolor vel pharetra mollis.">
                        </li>
                        <!-- End Item Project -->

                        <!-- Item Project and Filter Name -->
                        <li class="item-thumbs span3 video">
                            <!-- Fancybox Media - Gallery Enabled - Title - Link to Video -->
                            <a class="hover-wrap fancybox-media" data-fancybox-group="video" title="Video Content From Vimeo" href="http://vimeo.com/50834315"></a>
                            <!-- Thumb Image and Description -->
                            <img src="_include/img/work/thumbs/image-09.jpg" alt="Video">
                        </li>
                        <!-- End Item Project -->

                        <!-- Item Project and Filter Name -->
                        <li class="item-thumbs span3 design">
                            <!-- Fancybox - Gallery Enabled - Title - Full Image -->
                            <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="The Dark" href="_include/img/work/full/image-06-full.jpg"></a>
                            <!-- Thumb Image and Description -->
                            <img src="_include/img/work/thumbs/image-06.jpg" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis elementum odio. Curabitur pellentesque, dolor vel pharetra mollis.">
                        </li>
                        <!-- End Item Project -->

                        <!-- Item Project and Filter Name -->
                        <li class="item-thumbs span3 design">
                            <!-- Fancybox - Gallery Enabled - Title - Full Image -->
                            <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="The Beach" href="_include/img/work/full/image-07-full.jpg"></a>
                            <!-- Thumb Image and Description -->
                            <img src="_include/img/work/thumbs/image-07.jpg" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis elementum odio. Curabitur pellentesque, dolor vel pharetra mollis.">
                        </li>
                        <!-- End Item Project -->
                    </ul>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- End Portfolio Projects -->


        <!-- End Title Page -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to align exactly?

Comment: @Srax Ah sorry I should have mentioned that. I am trying to align the images so that `section` with id `projects`

Comment: Can you provide the HTML and CSS, would make it easier to help you.

Comment: I modified the question

Comment: Would be alot easier if you could provide us with the HTML and CSS you are having trouble with. I can only guess what changes you made to the template you linked :(

Comment: I dont know where the css is to modify the `section` i dont know how that margin is being applied or even if its a margin. Also the section is quite long. You can download the source code from http://www.alessioatzeni.com/blog/brushed-template/ and its line 167. Thanks alot

Comment: I know where i can download the source code, but you made some changes to your page that is not on the source code...

Comment: any ideas how i could fix it?

Comment: Working on it :)

Comment: thank you so much it really does mean a lot im still trying too. is it something to do with the span12 tag? looks like it has a -20px margin

Comment: Yeah, there is some -30px and -20px around... it's so annoying :(

Comment: if you do figure it out let me know, i am still trying if you give up also let me know :D thank youu

Comment: does that mean everything is not centered on the screen or only project section

Comment: Seems like everything with a `class="row"` or `span` tag is shifted either 20px  or 30px

Comment: I added an answer :) Check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the whole `<div class="container">` with the code below:
ps: I know you are not supposed to write CSS in HTML but it was they way i fixed it without having the CSS on my pc, you can move it to a stylesheet later.

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- Title Page -->
    <div class="row" style="
       text-align: center;
       padding-bottom: 30px;
       ">
        <h2 class="title">Our Work</h2>
        <h3 class="title-description">Check Out Our Projects on <a href="#">Dribbble</a>.</h3>
        <div class="title-page-less-margin">
            <nav id="options" class="work-nav">

                <ul id="filters" class="option-set" data-option-key="filter">
                    <a href="#filter" data-option-value="*" class="selected">All Projects</a>
                    <a href="#filter" data-option-value=".design">Design</a>
                    <a href="#filter" data-option-value=".photography">Photography</a>&lt;
                    <a href="#filter" data-option-value=".video">Video</a>
                </ul>

            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

        <section id="projects">
            <ul id="thumbs">

                <!-- Item Project and Filter Name -->
                <li class="item-thumbs span3 design">
                    <!-- Fancybox - Gallery Enabled - Title - Full Image -->
                    <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="The City" href="_include/img/work/full/image-01-full.jpg">

                                <span class="overlay-img"></span>
                                <span class="overlay-img-thumb font-icon-plus"></span>
                            </a>

                    <!-- Thumb Image and Description -->
                    <img src="_include/img/work/thumbs/image-01.jpg" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis elementum odio. Curabitur pellentesque, dolor vel pharetra mollis. hihihi">
                </li>
                <!-- End Item Project -->

                <!-- Item Project and Filter Name -->
                <li class="item-thumbs span3 design">
                    <!-- Fancybox - Gallery Enabled - Title - Full Image -->
                    <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="The Office" href="_include/img/work/full/image-02-full.jpg"></a>
                    <!-- Thumb Image and Description -->
                    <img src="_include/img/work/thumbs/image-02.jpg" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis elementum odio. Curabitur pellentesque, dolor vel pharetra mollis.">
                </li>
                <!-- End Item Project -->

                <!-- Item Project and Filter Name -->
                <li class="item-thumbs span3 photography">
                    <!-- Fancybox - Gallery Enabled - Title - Full Image -->
                    <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="The Mountains" href="_include/img/work/full/image-03-full.jpg"></a>
                    <!-- Thumb Image and Description -->
                    <img src="_include/img/work/thumbs/image-03.jpg" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis elementum odio. Curabitur pellentesque, dolor vel pharetra mollis.">
                </li>
                <!-- End Item Project -->

                <!-- Item Project and Filter Name -->
                <li class="item-thumbs span3 video">
                    <!-- Fancybox Media - Gallery Enabled - Title - Link to Video -->
                    <a class="hover-wrap fancybox-media" data-fancybox-group="video" title="Video Content From Vimeo" href="http://vimeo.com/51460511"></a>
                    <!-- Thumb Image and Description -->
                    <img src="_include/img/work/thumbs/image-08.jpg" alt="Video">
                </li>
                <!-- End Item Project -->

                <!-- Item Project and Filter Name -->
                <li class="item-thumbs span3 photography">
                    <!-- Fancybox - Gallery Enabled - Title - Full Image -->
                    <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="The Sea" href="_include/img/work/full/image-04-full.jpg"></a>
                    <!-- Thumb Image and Description -->
                    <img src="_include/img/work/thumbs/image-04.jpg" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis elementum odio. Curabitur pellentesque, dolor vel pharetra mollis.">
                </li>
                <!-- End Item Project -->

                <!-- Item Project and Filter Name -->
                <li class="item-thumbs span3 photography">
                    <!-- Fancybox - Gallery Enabled - Title - Full Image -->
                    <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Clouds" href="_include/img/work/full/image-05-full.jpg"></a>
                    <!-- Thumb Image and Description -->
                    <img src="_include/img/work/thumbs/image-05.jpg" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis elementum odio. Curabitur pellentesque, dolor vel pharetra mollis.">
                </li>
                <!-- End Item Project -->

                <!-- Item Project and Filter Name -->
                <li class="item-thumbs span3 video">
                    <!-- Fancybox Media - Gallery Enabled - Title - Link to Video -->
                    <a class="hover-wrap fancybox-media" data-fancybox-group="video" title="Video Content From Vimeo" href="http://vimeo.com/50834315"></a>
                    <!-- Thumb Image and Description -->
                    <img src="_include/img/work/thumbs/image-09.jpg" alt="Video">
                </li>
                <!-- End Item Project -->

                <!-- Item Project and Filter Name -->
                <li class="item-thumbs span3 design">
                    <!-- Fancybox - Gallery Enabled - Title - Full Image -->
                    <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="The Dark" href="_include/img/work/full/image-06-full.jpg"></a>
                    <!-- Thumb Image and Description -->
                    <img src="_include/img/work/thumbs/image-06.jpg" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis elementum odio. Curabitur pellentesque, dolor vel pharetra mollis.">
                </li>
                <!-- End Item Project -->

                <!-- Item Project and Filter Name -->
                <li class="item-thumbs span3 design">
                    <!-- Fancybox - Gallery Enabled - Title - Full Image -->
                    <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="The Beach" href="_include/img/work/full/image-07-full.jpg"></a>
                    <!-- Thumb Image and Description -->
                    <img src="_include/img/work/thumbs/image-07.jpg" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis elementum odio. Curabitur pellentesque, dolor vel pharetra mollis.">
                </li>
                <!-- End Item Project -->
            </ul>
        </section>

    </div>
</div>
```

Should look like this:
[image]

Comment: Wow no way it works!!! thanks so much. So for everything using row or span how would I fix it? because nothing is aligned now except projects

Comment: No problem, glad i could help.
Editing a template can be a real pain in the ass unfortunately.

Can you try to send me you whole project. You could upload as a zip somewhere and send me a download link :)

Comment: Here you go https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aGTPj3ojSZeJNFkwHCx_K-_9Avf3rxAj seriously dude im so happy you could help you have no idea how long i was trying to fix it before i posted the question

Comment: are you modifying the css so everything aligns properly?

Comment: I am trying but it is a real pain :(

Comment: Now you mentioned they are all not aligned im trying too. its really annoying why implement the website like this? haha. Thanks again though

Comment: It's funny how the image grid is only slightly shifted to the right when it's in full screen. If you resize the window it fits fine .

Comment: To be honest, i would just leave it as it is, or use another template. It's almost impossible to fix without redoing the whole template.

Comment: The image grid is made so it resizes the images to the page size so it "fits".

Comment: urgh I really liked this template :(

Comment: Well it still works, only problem is the image grid if a bit off :)

Comment: I changed this css to this: 
`h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6{
 margin:0 0px 20px 20px;
 color:#FFFFFF;
 font-weight:300;
 font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
 line-height:1.5em;
}`

Comment: Okay, did it fix it?

Comment: it now looks like this. do you tihnk this is all straight? https://gyazo.com/3e30f12ce457668c7a302b29b97a1110

Comment: If its not too much bother would you be able to make that change on your local version and see if it all aligns. In inspect element I still think it looks abit funny

Comment: Looks like it disapears when i hover over the top button

Comment: take a look at my copy https://drive.google.com/open?id=1A5gO4j10DZFE4TjLrkP6KrKuAsqPrHhI     I realised this is the only thing i need to change because the headers are the only other problem

Comment: also what do you personally think of the template :D

Comment: The template looks fine, but whoever made it didn't make the template easy to edit

Comment: so if i add `margin-right: 20px` everywhere will that offset the stupid `row` and `container`s?

Comment: Doubt it since it's made to be responsive, worth a shot tho